# Trying to have a formula that only works if cell greater than zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am working on a formula to try and include a formula only when we have identified additional items for one supplier and if there are no additional parameters it should just return the original score.

Currently my formula is:

```vb
=E23/(SUM(COUNTIF(E8:E22,{"<0",">0"}))*25)
```

which works for if a supplier has come back with additional parameters and basically turns it into a score. My issue is if i have a supplier that doesn't return any parameters I cant get it to just carry over the original score. If tried the following

```vb
=IF(F23<0,(F23/(SUM(COUNTIF(F8:F22,{"<0",">0"}))*25)),0)
```

I thought this would work as I am summing the total parameter value and therefore if it is greater than 0 it should go through the formula otherwise the figure I want back is 0

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my formula was wrong

```vb
=IF(B23>0,(B23/(SUM(COUNTIF(B8:B22,{"<0",">0"}))*25)),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this if you don't want a division of zero problems

```vb
=IF(SourceCell<>0,(SourceCell/DivisionFactor),(0))
```

Returns value or zero

ie:

```vb
=IF(W5<>0,(W5/2),(0))
```